# how to show toast notification or popup notification in win 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, toast

Hi I've read the toast notification and sample code in win8.

In fact, I want to show that :

http://cybernetnews.com/windows-8-desktop-notifications/

When user do something in desktop, it will show the first notification.

When user touch the first notification,  it will show the second notification.
And the second notification have some object can be select.

But I have no idea.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: This is not the proper way to ask a question at SO.  Surely other people have tried toasts, that's not really what you want to know.  Be very specific about the exact problem you are having getting them to work.  And post a snippet of your code.

Comment: Also - when talking about Windows 8 Metro Style Apps - it might be good to mention which language you would like to see the answer in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that. Behavior like that is reserved to the system (winrt). You can display a toast notification and react to the onclick event. But it's not possible to display controls or sth. like this. To get an overview what toast notiications can look like, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494).

Answer (score 0):

By the screenshot in the URL, the "second toast" is not a toast. It looks like a flyout menu.

Here is the information you want to know about how to implement Toast Notification
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx

The `click` event you mentioned is the [`onactivated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.activated.aspx) of a Toast Notification, implemented like this:

```
function onActivated(eventArgs) { /* Your code */ }
toastNotification.onactivated = onActivated;
```

And, `WinJS.UI.Flyout` is introduced here too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx